# QT QTreeView click event on specific column

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I have a quick question.  I want to intercept click events on a treeview with different behaviors based on which column is clicked.  I believe there is a signal which passes the model index... but how to identify the column? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I found the answer.. index.column() right?

Answer (score 1):

Check QItemSelectionModel used in the QTreeView to handle selection or click event in a row o column. Make your treeview selectable and used one of the default signals. You have 3 different signal to handle a click event:

```
void    currentChanged(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
void    currentColumnChanged(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
void    currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex &current, const QModelIndex &previous)
```

Handle the signal with a custom slot, and use QModelIndex parameter to get the current row and index. Example:

```
void MainWindow::elementClicked(const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex& previous) {
     const int row =  current.row();
     const int column = current.column();
     qDebug() << "Clicked at " << row << column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean:
Check QItemSelectionModel used in the QTreeView
?

Comment: The signals i have attached are signals of the QItemSelectionModel class. The QTreeView has a default QItemSelectionModel which notify every item selected/deselected in the tree. So check the: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qtreeview-members.html